# Separate tags from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, tags

I am building a blog which has tags.

The tags are saved to the DB like so `tag1,tag2,tag3` I would like to display these separately is there a way to separate these when echoing them out?

Thanks

Comment: Never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: [Normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pizza  = "piece1,piece2,piece3,piece4,piece5";
$pieces = explode(",", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Use `count` with a `for` loop or just a `foreach` to iterate over the array `$pieces`

```
foreach($pieces as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[Demo](http://codepad.org/p7ivRPaq)

Comment: Thanks for this, so would i need to list all the possible tags in the `$pizza  = "piece1,piece2,piece3,piece4,piece5";` part?

Comment: For each row from your table, yes.